# Chef: Split up custom resources with provides keyword?

Tags: chef-infra

[Chef's documentation](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources/#provides) suggests that you can split up your Custom Resources by OS with a provides keyword so you can use the same Custom Resource without bundling all the OS logic into a single file. That said, I can't find any example of how this is used. I've looked through all the Sous-Chef repos and this [blog post](https://blog.chef.io/chef-12-provider-resolver) but no solid examples.

How can I make it so Custom Resource "Foo" has a file tailor made for Windows and another for Linux?

```rb
provides :my_custom_resource, platform: 'redhat' do |node|
  node['platform_version'].to_i >= 7
end

provides :my_custom_resource, platform: 'redhat'

provides :my_custom_resource, platform_family: 'rhel'

provides :my_custom_resource, os: 'linux'

provides :my_custom_resource
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent all yesterday on this so figures I find the answer right after I ask about it.

**foo/resources/default.rb**

```rb
actions [:install, :remove]
default_action :install

# properties or attributes
```

**foo/resources/ubuntu.rb**

```rb
provides :foo, platform: 'ubuntu' do |node|
  node['platform_version'].to_f >= 16.04
end

# properties or attributes

# do ubuntu stuff
```

**foo/resources/windows.rb**

```rb
provides :foo, os: 'windows'

# properties or attributes

# do windows stuff
```

Comment: This means the default resource will be used for any other os than ubuntu or windows (just to stress the point)